# Python replacing literal \n

Tags: python, escaping, special-characters

I didn't want to ask here because I eventually got this to work, but I don't understand why my other attempts were not viable. It is driving me insane. I looked up so many forums.

Currently I have

```
filedata.replace('\\n','')
```

which removed literal `\n`, followed by

```
filedata = re.sub("': ;\d{5,6},\n'",', ',filedata)
```

to remove the subsequent "crap" in my output file

I could not, for the life of me, put this into one command. I don't know what I am missing, but this is because I cannot escape `\n` in `re.sub` (`\\n` does not work). And, I cannot escape `,` in `filedata.replace`; `\,` did not work, but `\'` works to escape `'`.

**EDIT**

Input:

```
Foo\nBarFoo,
Foo\nBarFoo
```

Desired Output:

```
FooBarFoo, FooBarFoo
```

This works:

```
filedata = filedata.replace('\\n','')
filedata = re.sub(",\n",', ',filedata)
```

so the first line replaces `literal \n` and second line replaces `literal ,` and newline (`\n`). What I could not do is get `.replace` to escape `,` (`\,`, etc. did not work) nor can I escape `\n` (newline) in `.sub` (`\\n`, etc. did not work). So I had to do it in two different steps, while I would prefer to do both in one.

I understand there are other ways to just remove characters if I am not actually replacing, this is just a simplified example of what I am doing. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to replace a backslash followed by an n, or a newline character ```\n``` ?

Comment: Could you show some inputs along with desired outputs? Otherwise it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The difficulty with trying to match backslash n in a regular expression is that backslash n is regex code for a newline. So ```\n``` is a newline character, and ```\\n``` is a pattern that matches a newline (but doesn't match backslash n). So if you want to match actual backslash n, you could use the pattern ````\\\\n```` in your regular expression.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit with more information

Comment: when you write a regex in python, try with raw string, e.g., `r"': ;\d{5,6},\n'"`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two "one-liners" but both require chaining two replace methods.

```
>>> filedata = 'Foo\nBarFoo,\nFoo\nBarFoo'

>>> filedata.replace(',\n', ', ').replace('\n', '')
'FooBarFoo, FooBarFoo'

>>> filedata.replace('\n', '').replace(',', ', ')
'FooBarFoo, FooBarFoo'
```